# Can I use a normal USB-keyboard on an iPad3 with iOS6.0?

Tags: ipad, usb, ios

Is there any way to use a normal USB-keyboard on an iPad3 with iOS6?

I saw a demo on YouTube where a normal USB-keyboard was connected to an iPad using the USB-connector. This iPad had iOS 5 on board.  I later read that this wouldn't function anymore under iOS 6.

I consider buying a connection set, but am reluctant since I want to use it to connect my normal USB keyboard. No use buying it if it won't work.

Answer (score -2):

Absolutely bizarre! I've just tried it with an Apple USB Keyboard on an iPad3 running iOS6 and it gives me an error saying the device draws too much power! So the answer is no! Another bizarre move by Apple.

Comment: That USB connection is to try to charge the iPad and not use the keyboard. To charge you need to connect directly to the computer or use a powered hub. This is a USB design issue not Apple

Comment: I'm talking about the usb connection kit not the 30pin to usb lead - and on the 1st gen ipad it powers the keyboard fine... keyboards don't use a huge amount of power and the usb spec allows for 5v as far as I know.